# C#.NET coming from PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net

I am coming from PHP so bear with me with my noobness...

I want to know a few things.

I know PHP, javascript and MySQL very very well now and I understand that browsers understand a few things.. html and javascript.

I ran through a tutorial of c#.net and found that it had pre-made "user controls" and i thought, oh my it's completely different from PHP... Then i realised that in the end it ends up with a bunch of javascript I could have written myself (not saying i want to ;), just saying).

My questions....

***1.***

If I have a table with some input fields:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method = "post" action = "validate_entry.aspx">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name: </td><td><input type = "text" name = "name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan = "2"><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and use the post and action methods, and then in validate_entry.aspx on Page_Load class I call something like:

```
c.Request["name"];
```

and do whatever with it.. Is this still a professional way of using c# or am i wanting it to be too much like PHP. Am i missing out on some execute speed or something even though it's running javascript.

***2.***

If I wanted to simply output the word "arse" in a div... If I do something like this, am I defeating the object of c#.net

```
<div id = "the_butt_holder">
    <% Response.Write("arse"); %>
</div>
```

or a better example is that in my validate_entry.aspx page I do:

```
<div id = "the_response">
    <% Response.Write(c.Request["name"]); %>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: MVC doesn't generate anything you don't tell it to generate. If you're unhappy with WebForms' inclination to generate a whole heap of extra markup/javascript for you.. learn MVC :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case, you would benefit greatly from looking at ASP MVC.  It gets much closer to the grain and will probably  be much closer to what you're used to working with as you have a great deal of control over the html.

Comment: ASP MVC, i can still use C# as my core language to generate the stuff PHP usually would.. but I can use my knowledge of html and javascript to control everything else?

Comment: Yes, C# is the main language supported.  I'm not sure on how you were using PHP (inline vs MVC, etc) but you would use C# to populate models, and you would use markup very similar to what you'd be used to using in PHP in the html. Check out  [this link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1]) and you'll be up and running in no time.

Comment: Spot on, cheers mate. (I found the link myself, don't worry.)

Answer (score 0):

Well James, I think you could start using asp.net mvc. It will be so easier to you than asp.net webforms. WebForms is based on Server Controls and Events, you cannot set a page in  tag, instad of it you can create a , double click in it and write your code on .cs file respective of your webform, then, the .net framework will do a thing called PostBack and executes this event. There's a desnecessary long life cycle when a PostBack runs.

In Asp.Net webForms you don't have control of your output HTML code. The SErver Controls will do it for you, and sometimes it is not you want (or need).

With ASP.NET MVC you have a Route Tables and you have a MVC Architecture Pattern, so, if you use a mvc framework in PHP, it would be easy for you. With ASp.NET MVC you have control of your HTML, and you can create Typed Views. Check this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your way is by no means wrong, however there is another way in ASP.NET, which is to use actual TextBox (which renders input field) control instead of input field directly. That way, you will be able to access value as a property of the control.

> ```
> <asp:TextBox id="tb1" runat="server" />
> var text = tb1.Text;
> ```

1. Why not just write literal directly instead of outputting it like this?

> ```
> <div id = "the_butt_holder">
>     arse
> </div>
> ```

---

You may feel much more at home using [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc), and Razor layout engine. It's much more like PHP and Smarty (or whatever similar templating engine replaced it nowdays :) )
You can find more than enough tutorials [right there on the site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos) to get you started.

Comment: The real question to ask is, if someone is calling themselves a C# ASP.NET developer, what is their typical approach to creating a website that is like, for example, stackoverflow.com